# TFS in VS2015 works for .csproj, not for adding .cs

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

Three computers all running Visual Studio 2015 with all current updates. All three machines have Bitlocker running.

Same problem occurs on all three machines, all three were working fine perhaps a week ago (last time I used this solution).

I use VisualStudio.com for TFS.

Today I got latest, added a file to a project I was working on, edited it and went to check in. I noticed it wasn't in the pending list. HOWEVER, the .sln was checked out and the .csproj was updated.
I could manually add the .cs file to TFS and it happily checked it in. It just won't do it automatically.

I then created a new project and added it to TFS and this worked fine.

I opened another existing solution and that also works fine.

So I duplicated the whole solution directory and attempted to add it with TFS power tools and NOW I see the problem.

```
Excluded by the global exclusion list: *.lib
```

My guess, and it's only a guess, is that in the last update, pushed out in the last couple of weeks they've added some exclusion for something "webby" which is screwing up my solution that happens to have a project with .lib at the end. Or perhaps file level filters are now applying to directories?

1) Where are these exclusions set?

2) Anyone know if this is a new exclusion added recently? As I said, I've worked on this solution for a year or more on and off without problem until today.

3) Which language prefers *.lib to be excluded? It makes sense for files, but this is applied to entire directories called MyProject.Lib (for example).

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a .tfignore file somewhere in your project folder or in one of the root folders of your project?

Comment: I do have a .tfignore. It's never changed (it just excludes nuget stuff) and I tried deleting it just in case it was suddenly causing a problem. It's definitely a global exclusion that has appeared recently that applies to folders named *.lib (case insensitive) :(  I've fixed it in the short term by just renaming anything that was MyProject.Lib to MyProjectLib. But I'm not happy that something has changed transparently to make me do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global exclusion list is configured by the server, there isn't any way to change it. You can get the detailed list from following path:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\X.0\Configuration\VersionControl\LocalItemExclusions.config
```

And I can get the same behavior as you with VS2015 Update3, but cannot see this issue with VS2015 Update2.

Comment: Ah great thank you. I can see the exclusion in the file. I assume it's overwritten each time it connects to the server. I use VisualStudio.com for my TFS and I couldn't find a way to change exclusions there. I'll keep looking, and I'll try and report it to the VisualStudio.com people.